# update a table where id is equal to 3 and add plus one to the already existing value in updatecount column

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I am attempting to update a table where its id is equal 3 and to increase a column called updatecount for example if the value in the column was 3 let it add one and make it 4. Here is my table structure

Images

```
id | photo | updatecount |
1     xyz  |   3
```

If I update the photo again where id is equal to 1 then the result becomes

```
id | photo | updatecount |
1     xyz  |   4
```

Here is my controller definition

```
public function upDateAction(Request $request)
    {
      $intid = (int)$request->request->get('imageid'); //convert the request object to int
$image = new Image();
... //to do updating here
```

**EDITTED**

Here is my model >>>

```
/**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="photo", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $photo;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="updatecount", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $updatecount;
```

Comment: Do you just need the SQL?
UPDATE images SET updatecount=updatecount+1 WHERE id=1;

Comment: Nope. I am doing it in symfony using doctrine

Comment: @Float Can you show your model?

Comment: Have shown my model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this should do the required job

```
public function upVoteAction(Request $request)
{
    $intid = (int)$request->request->get('imageid'); //convert the request object to int
    $em = $this->getContainer()->get('doctrine')->getManager();
    $image = $em->getRepository('YourBundle:Image')->find($intid);
    $image->setUpdatecount($image->getUpdatecount() + 1);
    $em->persist($image);
    $em->flush();
}
```

First get your image object from repository `getRepository()` using the image id. Then set `updatecount` as `setUpdatecount()` by increment in existing value

Comment: if you are in a controller, you dont need `getContainer`. You already have access by implements `ContainerAwareInterface`. `$this->getDoctrine()...`